# Why wont Eclipse @Override?

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding

I am following along with the Java for Dummies book and I ran into a problem. I can't figure out why @Override isn't working. I'm sure it has to do with my code because I have gotten a polymorphic array to work with override before, but it was too simple for me to mimic.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class DoPayrollTypeP {



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("EmpInfoNew.txt"));
    Scanner kbdScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    for(int empNum = 1; empNum<=3; empNum++){
        payOneFTEmployee (diskScanner);
    }
    for(int empNum = 4; empNum<=6; empNum++){
        payOnePTEmployee(diskScanner, kbdScanner);
    }
}
    public static void payOneFTEmployee(Scanner diskScanner){

        FullTimeEmployee ftemployee = new FullTimeEmployee();
        ftemployee.setName(diskScanner.nextLine());
        ftemployee.setJobTitle(diskScanner.nextLine());
        ftemployee.setWeeklySalary(diskScanner.nextDouble());
        ftemployee.setBenefitDeduction(diskScanner.nextDouble());
        diskScanner.nextLine();
        diskScanner.nextLine();

        ftemployee.cutCheck(ftemployee.findPaymentAmount());
        out.println();
    }

    public static void payOnePTEmployee(Scanner diskScanner, Scanner  kbdScanner) {
        PartTimeEmployee ptemployee = new PartTimeEmployee();
        ptemployee.setName(diskScanner.nextLine());
        ptemployee.setJobTitle(diskScanner.nextLine());
        ptemployee.setHourlyRate(diskScanner.nextDouble());
        diskScanner.nextLine();
        diskScanner.nextLine(); //Reads the dashed line that
        // separates two employees
        out.print("Enter ");
        out.print(ptemployee.getName());
        out.print("'s hours worked this week: ");
        int hours = kbdScanner.nextInt();
        ptemployee.cutCheck(ptemployee.findPaymentAmount(hours));
        out.println();
        }
}
```

Next class:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;



    public void setName(String nameIn) {
        name = nameIn;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleIn) {
        jobTitle = jobTitleIn;
    }
    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid){
        out.printf("Pay to the order of %s", name);
        out.printf("(%s) ***$", jobTitle);
        out.printf("%,.2f\n", amountPaid);

    }


}
```

Next Class:

```
public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee{

private double hourlyRate;

public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRateIn) {
    hourlyRate = hourlyRateIn;
}
public double getHourlyRate() {
    return hourlyRate;
}

public double findPaymentAmount(int hours){
    return hourlyRate * hours;
    } //method that should be overriden
}
```

Class That should override:

```
public class PartTimeWithOver extends PartTimeEmployee{

@Override
public double findPaymentAmount(int hours) {
if(hours <= 40) {
return getHourlyRate() * hours;
} else {
return getHourlyRate() * 40 +
getHourlyRate() * 2 * (hours - 40);
}
}

}
```

EmpInfoNew.(txt) file

jo shmo
Ceo
5000.00

### 500.00

edd shmoe
Captain
5000.00

### 500.00

bob shmo
Honorary Exec
1000.00

### 200.00

Dave shmo
driver

### 7.25

edd blah
Cook

### 8.50

len shmo
Head of Kitchen

### 12.50

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you explicitly making a PartTimeWithOver object to call the overridden method rather than making a PartTimeEmployee?

Comment: im not getting an error but the math is wrong

Comment: no im not making an object. i would assume that i would not have to do that since the method would be called in main and due to polymorphism it would be overridden in the PartTimeWithOver class

Comment: In the main class you make have: PartTimeEmployee ptemployee = new PartTimeEmployee(); This only makes a PartTimeEmployee not a PartTimeWithOver. So when findPaymentAmount is called it is not overriding since you have the superclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have instantiated object as

```
PartTimeEmployee ptemployee = new PartTimeEmployee();
```

It is a `base` class of `PartTimeWithOther` so it cannot call `overridden` method in `derived` class.

Change to

```
PartTimeEmployee ptemployee = new PartTimeWithOver();
```

[Here](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html) is an nice tutorial with diagrams that explains **Polymorphism**

Answer (score 0):

You never use PartTimeWithOver, you only work with PartTimeEmployee.

So your overriden method is never called.